# Transfer Tableview cell image to another view using swift 2.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

how to transfer tableview cell image to detail view for example i want to display the cell image in another view controller when ever user will click on cell

I have searched but not got the prefect answer...

thank you..

here is my code

Source viewController

```
var tweakImage: UIImage! //here I have stored the cell Image
override func prepareForSegue….{

detailVC.tweakDetailImage = tweakImage // here i am sending it to another view

}
```

Destination view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var tweakImageView: UIImageView! // image view in destination view controller where i have to set the image

view didLoad{
tweakImageView.image = tweakDetailImage
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in `prepareForSegue` method

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var row = tblViewTest.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
        //Fetch object/value for the row selected from array or dictionary
        // let say "objectAtIndex"

        var newViewController = segue.destinationViewController
        newViewController.objectSelected = objectAtIndex
    }
```

Make sure to make an object with name `objectSelected` in second view controller

```
        if segue.identifier == "ImageScene" {

            var row = tblViewTest.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
            var imageName: String = "\(row!).jpg"   //Unwrapping forcefully
            var newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ImageViewController
            newViewController.imageSelected = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
```

Unwrapping is done forcefully for imageName as I am sure that row would have a value as I have performed the segue on UITableView's didSelectRowAtIndex method, now I can successfully see the image on my second view controller

Comment: how are you displaying the image in cellForRowAtIndex method?

Comment: Sir, let say for example  i have stored the image in UIImage and want to display in ImageView in detailVC

Comment: Have you tried to send image as NSData rather than UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your datasource object to your detailController. There must be some data source using which you are setting image on cell. Pass it to your detail controller instance when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is being tapped.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Muneeba.. as u said to set data source it working if it is a text but in case of image "error"

Comment: In your DetailsViewController, you wrote cell.image = detailImage but i don't see any cell variable in your detail controller. paste the error you are getting.

Comment: its not giving any error, just not not working ...cell is the IBOutlet imageView were the image should display..

Comment: what is this 'cell' variable in your detailController. i don't see any declaration for it

Comment: hope the update code may clear  my issue to you...:)

Comment: okay make sure tweakImageView 's outlet is connected, also make sure that tweakImage is a UIImage

Comment: As u have said its like that only..but not working :(

Comment: Log tweakImage , make sure you are getting the image.